# How to parse MySQL slow query log for last 24 hours of entries

Tags: mysql, linux, awk, sed, grep

I'd like to process my MySQL Slow Query log and retrieve the last 24 hours of entries, Log rotation isn't an option at present.

Below is an example log entry

```
# Query_time: 0.000431  Lock_time: 0.000124 Rows_sent: 8  Rows_examined: 25
SET timestamp=1415792064;
SELECT `username`, `password`, `date_created` From joomla_users
ORDER BY `kid` DESC;
# User@Host: joomla[joomla] @  [192.168.168.100]
```

I would like to use awk or grep or a similar solution that could be executed via command line or as part of a script to identify the entries placed in the mysql slow query log file within the last 24 hours by comparing the "SET TIMESTAMP" line for each entry and place said entries into a separate log file.

Answer (score 0):

I would very strongly recommend using Percona Toolkit's query digest tool for this sort of analysis. It's straightforward to install and basically does exactly what you'd want an analysis of slow queries to do (analyze them based on query footprints, not the individual arguments in the queries, exclude certain types of queries based on REGEX expressions, etc)

Take a look into the Percona Toolkit (http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html). If you decide to use it, the following code should be easy to adapt

```
pt-query-digest --since '2014-11-01' --filter '$event->{arg} =~ m/^select/i' /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow-query.log > /tmp/pt_slow_nov
```

What that's saying is analyze queries from 2014-11-01 onward, only look at select queries, read the slow query log from /var/log/mysql/slow-query.log (obviously you'll need to reference your file location) and output the analysis to /tmp/pt_slow_nov. If you're familiar with grep and awk, it should be pretty straightforward to parameterize the --since portion of this query and stick it in a cron.